# Why do I get same result with toString() but different result with getClass().getName()

Tags: java, spring, proxy, aop, aspect

I am learning AOP, in the spring project, I have the following piece of code.

`MainDemoApp.java`

```
public class MainDemoApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // read spring config java class
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DemoConfig.class);

        // DemoConfig.class is a simple class with just component scanning enabled 
        // and with @EnableAspectJAutoProxy

        // get the bean from spring container
        AccountDAO accountDAO = context.getBean("accountDAO", AccountDAO.class);

        System.out.println(accountDAO.toString()); // line to be modified

        // call the business method
        accountDAO.addAccount();

        // close the context
        context.close();
    }
}
```

`AccountDAO.java`

```
@Component
public class AccountDAO {
    public void addAccount() {
        System.out.println(this.toString()); // line to be modified
    }
}
```

and my aspect class
`MyDemoLoggingAspect.java`

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyDemoLoggingAspect {

    // this is where we add all our related advices for logging

    // let's start with a @Before advice
    @Before("execution(public void addAccount())")
    public void beforeAddAccountAdvice() {
        System.out.println("\n=======>>> Executing @Before Advice");
    }
}
```

Now when I run `main` method in `MainDemoApp`, I get the following output-
Output-

```
com.luv2code.aopdemo.dao.AccountDAO@3e0e1046

=======>>> Executing @Before Advice
com.luv2code.aopdemo.dao.AccountDAO@3e0e1046
```

As you can see the lines

```
System.out.println(accountDAO.toString());
```

And

```
System.out.println(this.toString());
```

give the same result, before advice is also executed successfully.
By default `toString()` is defined as-

```
this.getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(this.hashCode())
```

But when I explicitly print out getClass().getName() the results are different

```
System.out.println(accountDAO.getClass().getName());
```

And

```
System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
```

Output-

```
com.luv2code.aopdemo.dao.AccountDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88eb61b6

=======>>> Executing @Before Advice
com.luv2code.aopdemo.dao.AccountDAO
```

Both the class names differ, I don't know which type of class name is that.
Also when I explicitly print `hashCode()` the results are different.

I am confused about getting different results with-

1. `toString()`, when `toString()` includes `getClass().getName()` and `hashCode()`
2. `getClass().getName()`
3. `hashCode()`

Why are these differences there, I did not override any of these methods (At my end), does this has something related to AOP proxy?

Kindly help me clarify these doubts.

Edit-
I also have a very strange observation that when I modify
`MainDemoApp.java`

```
AccountDAO accountDAO = context.getBean("accountDAO", AccountDAO.class);

System.out.println(accountDAO.hashCode());
// call the business method
accountDAO.addAccount(accountDAO);
```

And `AccountDAO.java` is modified as-

```
public void addAccount(AccountDAO obj) {
        System.out.println(this.hashCode() + " " + obj.hashCode());
}
```

**NOW the result of `hashCode()` is the same but if I don't change the method signature and call `hashCode()` on the previous piece of code, the result is different**

Can anyone explain this also?

Comment: The proxy `toString` probably just delegates to the wrapped class' `toString`. Other than that, the proxy itself is a different type, therefore `getClass` returns something different

Comment: I mean that's believable but if you can come with the code snippet I would be ready to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @QBrute I edited the question with another part, please take a look

Comment: @QBrute Your first comment may justify my first part of the query ( without edit ) but I don't think it explains the edit.

Comment: Did you adjust your aspect when you made the changes in your edit?

Comment: I just changed the signature of the method of `AccountDAO`, nothing was done to the aspect

Comment: So the aspect didn't match and your bean wasn't proxied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Welcome to SO. Please note that on this platform, it would be better to ask just one clear question and not lots of them. But we also try to be nice to newbies, so I am trying to answer your questions. While this is somewhat redundant, because others have replied in comments already, I also think that comments are comments and answers are answers, i.e. an answer should be written as such. Probably the other contributors here are too busy to write a comprehensive answer, so I am picking up the ball here.*

> ```java
> System.out.println(accountDAO.toString());
> ```
>
> And
>
> ```java
> System.out.println(this.toString());
> ```
>
> give the same result

This is because `accountDAO` is a dynamic proxy and you are applying a Spring AOP aspect to it. It is forwarding method calls to its delegate (the original object it is proxying).

> But when I explicitly print out getClass().getName() the results are different
>
> ```java
> System.out.println(accountDAO.getClass().getName());
> ```
>
> And
>
> ```java
> System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
> ```
>
> Output-
>
> ```
> com.luv2code.aopdemo.dao.AccountDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88eb61b6
>
> =======>>> Executing @Before Advice
> com.luv2code.aopdemo.dao.AccountDAO
> ```

The former prints the name of the CGLIB proxy class, the latter the target class name.

> Also when I explicitly print `hashCode()` the results are different.

Same reason: You are printing the hash code of the proxy vs. the original object.

> Why are these differences there, I did not override any of these methods (At my end), does this has something related to AOP proxy?

Well, in a way you did. You applied an aspect, causing proxy creation. So now the actual Spring bean is a proxy, causing all the effects you described above. Technically, a Spring proxy is a subclass (or interface implementation, depending on your settings and whether you are proxying an interface ot class type). The proxy keeps a reference to the original object (its delegate or target object), decorating it with additional functionality. This is a well-known design pattern. Spring makes heavy use of it throughout the framework. See [my explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56616248/1082681) for more details.

As for your follow-up question, the root cause and explanation are the same as above. It is all quite straightforward and logical, once you understand that Spring AOP uses dynamic proxies and same proxies use delegation in order to implement a [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: Thanks a ton for a detailed answer, will keep the tips in mind.