# What exactly happen when method is annotate with @Transactional ? What is the need of creating proxy?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

What exactly happen when method is annotate with @Transactional ? Do @Transactional is called only when method contains database operations and what is the need of creating proxy

I have been asked this several times in interview but didn't get any clarification on reading answers from various blogs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring - @Transactional - What happens in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

Transactional annotation signals Spring to create a proxy around the created bean. Spring uses AOP under the hood to delegate transaction-related activities to the underlying TransactionManager. AOP code is going to be invoked regardless you actually use DB access in your method or not.
Having said that, there are [issues regarding self-invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614354/why-does-self-invocation-not-work-for-spring-proxies-e-g-with-aop) of transactional methods, but this is the shortcoming of Spring Syle AOP at large.

I suggest you take a look at Spring proxies, in which cases a bean is proxied and when it is not, and also get a general feel for AOP since it is used heavily under the hood in Spring.

Answer (score 0):

> `@Transactional` - When this annotation is declared at the class
> level, it applies as a default to all methods of the declaring class
> and its subclasses. Note that it does not apply to ancestor classes up
> the class hierarchy; inherited methods need to be locally redeclared
> in order to participate in a subclass-level annotation. For details on
> method visibility constraints, consult the Transaction Management
> section of the reference manual.

see

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html