# Issue closing data source connection

Tags: java, database-connection, datasource

I have a data source that is setup & then, used by a third party software to execute sql. After the sql is run I have another bean that executes & closes the connection.

```
@Bean
public DataSource datasource() {
    HikariConfig myconfig = new HikariConfig();
    ...
    return new HikariDataSource(myconfig);
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("sqlproject")
public void closeConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection c = datasource().getConnection();
    try {
        c.close();
    } 
    finally {
        System.out.println(c.isClosed());
    }
}
```

However, I can clearly still make local calls using that datasource connection to particular data. Should I not be calling `datasource()` because this creates a new instance ? What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, when you're calling `datasource` from configuration class, new instance is created because [Spring AOP doesn't support self invocation via `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614354/why-does-self-invocation-not-work-for-spring-proxies-e-g-with-aop).

Moreover, even if you have used this AOP correctly, this wouldn't have closed `DataSource`, since you're creating new connection (via `getConnection()` and then closing it.

If you want to close `HikariDataSource`, then you need to call `HikariDataSource#close`.

Also, you don't need `@Bean` annotation on your `void` method since it makes no sense.

Comment: Would I need to call `HikariDataSource#close` within the same `datasource()` method ? How else would you close it without creating a new instance ? Also, strangely enough the `closeConnection()` method is not called when it does not have the `@Bean` annotation; I had the same thinking.

Comment: When do you need this method to be called?

Comment: I need it to be called after the "sqlproject" library completes its execution; which won't happen until the DataSource is already setup. I know for a fact that `closeConnection()` is always called afterwards which is why I was trying to use it. Would a `DriverManager#getConnection` be of use ?

Comment: If you need to call something after something completes, you need to use `@PreDestroy` annotation, `DisposableBean` interface or you can listen to `ContextRefreshedEvent` (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events) and perform code you want depending on `ApplicationContext` state

Comment: I thought `@PreDestroy` was for executing something in the very start of deletion process ? So, I would need a `DisposableBean` & then, create its own `destroy()` method I suppose.

Comment: `@PreDestroy` is pretty the same as `DisposableBean` it's called when a bean reaches the end of life

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239506/discussion-between-user3696953-and-geobreze).