# How can I implement nested logging within a Spring component with AspectJ?

Tags: java, spring, logging, aspectj

I'm working on a Spring Boot Gradle project with Java, where logging is done manually in every function that needs to be logged. In each function that requires logging, a new instance of a custom logger is initialized with the help of Lombok's @Cleanup annotation. The custom logger implements the AutoCloseable interface, so the @Cleanup annotation automatically closes the resource when the function ends. It works like this:

```
public void someFuction(String str) {
    @Cleanup var logging = new CustomLogger(log, "someFuction", str); //NOSONAR
    logging.startLogging();
    ....
    Some logic
    .....
}
```

The @Cleanup annotation essentially puts the code in a *try/finally* block, so it works something like this under the hood:

```
public void someFuction(String str) {
    try{
        CustomLogger logging = new CustomLogger(log, "someFuction", str); //NOSONAR
        logging.startLogging();
        ....
        Some logic
        .....
    } finally(){
        logging.close();
    }
}
```

This approach works fine, but having to copy two lines into every function that needs to be logged and manually passing the function name, logger, and parameters of the function every time does not seem like a "clean" solution, and it introduces critical Sonar problems as well.

So, I thought I could achieve the same effect easily with a custom annotation and with the help of Spring AOP, more specifically, the AspectJ library.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j; 
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint; 
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning; 
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing; 
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect; 
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect 
@Component 
@Slf4j 
public class LoggingAspect {
    private ThreadLocal<CustomLogger> businessLoggingThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Before("@annotation(Loggable)")
    public void logMethodStart(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();

        CustomLogger businessLogging = new CustomLogger(log, methodName, args);
        businessLoggingThreadLocal.set(businessLogging);
        businessLogging.logMethodStart();
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "@annotation(Loggable)", returning = "result")
    public void logMethodEnd(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
        CustomLogger businessLogging = businessLoggingThreadLocal.get();
        if (businessLogging != null) {
            businessLogging.close();
            businessLoggingThreadLocal.remove();
        }
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "@annotation(Loggable)", throwing = "exception")
    public void logMethodException(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable exception) {
        CustomLogger businessLogging = businessLoggingThreadLocal.get();
        if (businessLogging != null) {
            businessLogging.close();
            businessLoggingThreadLocal.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my custom annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Loggable {}
```

This "wrapper" around the existing logging mechanism seems fine at first glance, but it cannot perform nested logging within the same Spring component. If a method calls a method in another component, the logging works fine, but if it were to call a method in the same component, it simply does not log the other method.

For example:

```
@Service 
public class ExampleService { 
    .... 

    @Loggable 
    public void someMethod(){ 
        .... 
        some logic 
        .... 
        anOtherMethod(); 
    }

    @Loggable
    public void anOtherMethod(){
        ....
        some logic
        ....
    }
}
```

The expected logging would be:

```
Method started: someMethod()
Method started: anOtherMethod()
Method ended: anOtherMethod()
Method ended: someMethod()
```

But the actual logging, when both of the fuctions are in the same component, is:
(It works fine, the above mentioned way, if the anOtherMethod() in an a different component)

```
Method started: someMethod()
Method ended: someMethod()
```

I'm using this gradle plugin:
`id("io.freefair.aspectj") version "8.0.1"`

and this dependency:
`implementation("org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.7")`

It is possible to do nested logging in the same component with AspectJ?If not or if it is not recommended are there better ways to approach this problem?

Comment: If you do not like the `@Autowired` workaround, native AspectJ is the way to go. But then you need to decide if you want compile-time weaving (using the Freefair plugin in Gradle, like in your example above) or load-time weaving (using a java agant, as described in the Spring manual). Either way, you should then remove the `@Component` annotation from your aspect, because you do not want a native AspectJ aspect to be re-applied by Spring AOP. If you would share a minimal reproducer on GitHub, I could take a closer look. But there should be plenty examples here already.

Comment: One more thought: It looks quite inefficient to create a new logger instance for every method call. If I were you, I would not do that.

Comment: @kriegaex Thank you, your comment definitely help a lot. Since then I've managed to get the post comple weaving get to work and now the nested logging works. The only thing is that the logs at the start of a fuctions are printed twice. The end of the function log is only once. Have you ever come accross anything like this? 
I've removed the Component annotation, but there only one instance of the LoggingAspect class, I've tried making it a slingleton and the error persisted so thats not the problem.

Comment: @kriegaex

id("io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving") version "6.5.1"

options.compilerArgs.add("-Xlint:unchecked")
options.compilerArgs.add("-Xlint:deprecation")

tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    doFirst {
 options.compilerArgs.add("-Xlint:unchecked")
options.compilerArgs.add("-Xlint:deprecation")
}
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    doFirst {
        val aspectjweaverPath = configurations["testRuntimeClasspath"].find { it.name.contains("aspectjweaver") }
jvmArgs("-javaagent:${aspectjweaverPath}")
}}

These are the changes I made to the gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

It is like Spring AOP works. Aspects are not called when you call a method inside the same class, but only from outside of the class. However, if you want to enforce to have the Aspect called inside the same class, you can do something like this:

```
@Resource
private ExampleService self = this;

public void someMethod() {
    self.method2();
}

public void anOtherMethod() {

}
```

Check this out for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies

Comment: This approach introduces a circle in the dependencies, so it doesn't work. (I'm using Spring boot 3) I know that Spring AOP on its own should not be able to do this, but I've heard that AspectJ can be used for this, but do not find anything about it.

Comment: Sorry in more dept, I've heard that AspectJ's native weaving does not have this limitation. You can use AspectJ compiler (ajc) and its weaving capabilities to weave aspects at compile-time or load -time. This allows aspects to be applied even to internal method calls. But I've have not managed to find a way to properly use it.

Comment: Not being a Spring user, I never tried `@Resource`. But if you use `@Autowired`, it should work. There is no circular dependency. Fore more information about how Spring proxies work (and how they do not), and what the alternatives are, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56616248/1082681).

Answer (score 0):

> @kriegaex Thank you, your comment definitely help a lot. Since then I've managed to get the post comple weaving get to work and now the nested logging works. The only thing is that the logs at the start of a fuctions are printed twice.

As a previous Spring AOP user, you might be used to the fact that Spring AOP only knows `execution` joinpoints, but native AspectJ knows several more, most prominently `call` ones. I.e., for the same method, it can intercept the method call (in the calling method) and the method execution (in the called method).

> The end of the function log is only once.

That would surprise me. For the same method call/execution, the result should be consistent. Probably you overlooked or misinterpreted something in your log.

In order to see the difference, simply add something like

```java
System.out.println("[ENTER] " + joinPoint);
```

and

```java
System.out.println("[EXIT] " + joinPoint);
```

to your advice methods.

You can fix the problem in several ways, e.g. like this:

```java
@Before("@annotation(Loggable) && execution(* *(..))")
```

If you do not wish to repeat the same pointcut expression in 3 separate advice methods, simply factor them out into one `@Pointcut` expression, referring to the same pointcut in all advice methods.