# How to intercept nested method call with same annotation configured using Spring AOP or AspectJ?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have configured multiple database following this link https://fable.sh/blog/splitting-read-and-write-operations-in-spring-boot/. DB call is routed based on the Transactional annotation value. Call to DB is happening correctly till we try to make a nested call.

In my service class, I have 2 methods. One is performing read operation using Replica Server and another is performing write operation using Primary Server. But when I try to call read method inside write method, both DB calls routed through Primary server only. Below is code snippet for Service class

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
    
    @Transactional(readOnly = true) //Make a call to Replica Server
    public List<String> replica() {
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT QUERY";
        return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, (rs, rowNum) -> rs.getString(1));
    }
    
    @Transactional(readOnly = false) //Make a call to Primary Server
    public List<String> primary() {
        String sqlQuery = "INSERT QUERY";
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sqlQuery, params);
        
        return replica(); //DB call should be made to Replica Server but it's calling Primary Server
    }

}
```

Below is AOP configured to route DB calls to different server based on Transactional annotation

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(0)
@Slf4j
public class DataSourceRouteInterceptor {

    @Around("@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")
    public Object proceed(ProceedingJoinPoint call) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) call.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();

        Transactional tx = method.getAnnotation(Transactional.class);
        try {
            if (tx.readOnly()) {
                RoutingDataSource.setReplicaRoute();
                log.info("Routing DB call to Replica Server");
            }
            return call.proceed();
        } finally {
            RoutingDataSource.clearReplicaRoute();
        }
    }
}
```

My expectation is when I call replica method inside primary method, DB calls should be routed based on the Transactional annotation value configured on that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Spring AOP, therefore the self-invocation `return replica()` inside of `primary()` will never even trigger the aspect, as described in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56616248/1082681). You either need to use native AspectJ and set it up correctly, or you need to use the workaround described at the end of my answer under "Solutions", self-injecting the target object and calling the method on the self-injected proxy in order to trigger Spring AOP.

Comment: Never worked on Spring AOP or AspectJ before. Self-Injecting the Object worked for me. Is there any performance drawback of doing this?

Comment: No, I do not think so. The performance drawback compared to native AspectJ is always Spring AOP itself with its dynamic proxies. The self-injection does not matter performance-wise. It is just ugly, because the whole point of AOP is that the core code should be unaware of it. By self-injecting a bean in order to accommodate Spring AOP, you make the corresponding core class AOP-aware, which kind of defeats the whole idea. It is a workaround, and it works - no more, no less.