# AspectJ doesnt work properly in Spring project

Tags: spring, hibernate, persistence, aop, aspectj

I have my spring project (Not Spring Boot)
I turned on aspect with <aop:aspectj-autoproxy /> After I did it I have odd behaviour with my @PersistenceContext and @Transactional annotations.

When I had  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy  proxy-target-class="true"  /> I had error in my generic class only in case I had internal call of methods.
For example: when I called method delete externally ad method find was called internally from delete method. Check example below.
My generic class example:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class GenericServiceImpl<T extends IEntity<PK>, PK extends Serializable> implements IGenericService<T, PK> {
    private final Class<T> type;
    
    public GenericServiceImpl(final Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    private EntityManager em;
    
    @PersistenceContext
    public final void setEntityManager(final EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public final EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
 
    public final void delete(final PK pk) { // I call this method externally
        T o = find(pk); // internal call which didn't work
        if (o != null) {
            o.setDeleted(true);
            save(o);
        }
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)  // when I call this method externally everything works fine
    public final T find(final PK pk) {
        if (pk == null) {
            return null;
        }

        T o = em.find(type, pk); // In case I call find method from delete method em is null
        if (o != null && o.isDeleted()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return o;
        }
    }
}
```

When I had  aop:aspectj-autoproxy/  I had 2 problems:

- It was no possible to get parameters name in aspect

```java
MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
methodSignature.getParameterNames(); // here I had null
```

But in my case I worked around it by using autogenerated name of parameters (for my case it was enough).

- When I turned on proxy-target-class="true" `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
  I had error in my generic class only in case I had internal call of methods.
  For example: when I called method delete externally and method find was called internally from delete method.
  In this case my EntityManager was null.
  Check example above.

When I removed proxy-target-class="true"  `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` I fixed crash with em is null but I received odd methods behavior.
For example: After I called delete method my entity was deleted from database. But when I called the find the method I received previous state of entity.
It looks like my entity was cached in the persistence context.
How can I fix it?

JAVA version: 8
My POM deps (only meaningful):

```
    <spring.version>4.3.30.RELEASE</spring.version>
    ....
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.19</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You wrote a long-winded question, I tried to help you, and now you are not reacting. I do not find that particularly polite. Would you please provide some feedback?

Answer (score 0):

*This is a preliminary answer, too long to fit into a comment. I will update it, as the OP provides more information.*

It is a bit difficult for me to understand what you are trying to explain. I think I can help you, if you publish a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, adding context to your sample code. Please also make sure that the reproducer initialises and uses an in-memory DBMS like H2. Thank you.

When just copying & pasting your code fragment (with lots of missing classes referenced from it) into my IDE, I noticed the hint "Methods annotated with '@Transactional' must be overridable" on your final `find` method:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA warning]

Making it non-final should help, otherwise Spring AOP cannot create any proxy method for it.

Furthermore, if you expect self-invocation to trigger aspects - both your own ones and declarative ones like `@Transactional` - you cannot use Spring AOP, but have to switch to native AspectJ, because the latter is independent of proxies. BTW, it would also work with final methods. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56616248/1082681) to understand how Spring proxies work.